# Android simulator shows big transparent bulk on top

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

When I run my React Native app on Android emulator it shows a big ugly bulk on top of the screen:
[image]

The transparent bulk appears only on the android emulator but on physical mobile phones not.

The installed emulator version:
[image]

How to make the big ugly transparent bulk disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML Way:**

I can tell you the way how to remove that in Android Studio.

Go to your `themes.xml` or `styles.xml` in your `res` folder.
Add this two lines there:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

In your layout files for example you want to remove it in your `MainActivity.java` go to it's `XML` file called `activity_main.xml` and add this in the parent `View`:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

---

**JAVA Way:**

Other way, removing it by code. Paste the following code snippet in your `onCreate()` method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Your imports above the `class` are:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Comment: The Java way I like it. Could you please tell what for libraries do I have to import?

Comment: I added the imports :) Beside that there is nothing additional. Cheers :)